# Create gauges python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, plotly, gauge

How can I create gauges using matplotlib in a tkinter GUI in python in order to monitor speed?

I have had a look at plotly but do not understand how it can be used on pycharm development environment.

Similar questions that have been posted do not address gauges in specific.

I need to dispalay speed in a speedometer.

Is there any library available or does this need to be done using wedges and arrows in matplotlib?

Comment: I have edited the question, the marked answer does not answer my question. I need to design a gauge that looks like a speedometer.

Comment: Why are you specifically looking to do this with matplotlib? Why not just draw a widget with the tkinter canvas?

Comment: If using matplotlib, you would need to use some half circle and an arrow to get a speedometer. Note that questions asking for recommendations of external resources are off-topic. So technically we might reopen this question to directly close it as off-topic again. If you have a specific problem implementing your gauge, you may ask a specific question with the code and a clear problem description.

Comment: Hi Scotty3785, because I will be monitoring speed live and matplotlib seemed like the better way.